# ES6 modules: understanding import statement work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm pretty sure that the issue is not Angular specific. Still I met the problem in Angular

Consider the following code

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

console.log((window as any).external_component_stuff); // <- non-empty object outputed here
debugger; // needed to see state of window.external_component_stuff object

import { ExternalComponent } from '@scope/external-component';

// component code goes here ...
```

Nothing can create `window.external_component_stuff` in other places. Why is `window.external_component_stuff` not undefined before `import`?

Comment: ... maybe You could provide more info on what is in `ExternalComponent ` - it seems like it add to `window` object ..? ( otherwise - stuff is hoisted in JS, so maybe that's the catch ... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-hoisting/#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20Hoisting%20is%20the,scope%20is%20global%20or%20local. )

Comment: @Vovan_Super I do not have access to the components code. But obviously `window.external_component_stuff` is populated there